# Parsing TextFile

Tags: c#, string

First this is not a troll question and i really want to get a solution for this so please try to help me.

Well i have a string that contains a lot of numbers it is in the following Format

```
[Block1]
Item1
Item2
Item3

[Block2]
Item1
Item2
Item3

...SO ON
```

Well i have tried alot of things with no luck of which are

```
string.IndexOf
StreamReader
```

What i want to achieve is searching for [Block1] and return the values below it in an array.

I hope i had explained what i want to achieve clearly and thanks in advance,

Comment: i have tried to use indexof and stringreader and streamreader but i can't get to the point that makes my code searches for a tag and return it's content

Comment: try this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/858756/how-to-parse-a-text-file-with-c-sharp

Comment: this is not what i want to achieve

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It was a little too easy so I decided to make it a one-liner for added fun (formatted for readability):

```
IEnumerable<string> text = File.ReadAllLines(@"Path\To\File")
                               .SkipWhile(line => line != "[Block1]")
                               .Skip(1)
                               .TakeWhile(line => line != "[Block2]");
```

Of course, you have to replace the path to the text file.

And if it's not in a file but in a multiline string, you can replace

`File.ReadAllLines(@"Path\To\File")` with `myString.Split('\n')`

Comment: Can you tell me why i get this Exception : Illegal characters in path.

Comment: read the exception, Luke. The @ makes verbatim strings, without it you need to use \\ instead of \.