# DNN Module Import file

Tags: dotnetnuke

I'm making a module to import CODA files. It is a Belgian banking standard. I have seen around on the internet, and as of now, there is no existing module for DNN. There are snippets here and there and there's ODOO, but I need it in DNN. 
I'm not new to programming, but I am however new to web dev. I am trying to first import the file and then parse it. However, I can't seem to find any straightforward way of importing it. I tried to see the code here but was not able to adapt it for my need.

[How to parse a text file with C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/858756/how-to-parse-a-text-file-with-c-sharp)

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Please share your code

Answer (score 0):

You probably will need to create your own module to handle such specific requirements. There are tutorials out there, but I'd start by either create a simple module at `Host > Extensions > Create new extension` within DNN itself.

Or use the [Christoc's Module Template](https://github.com/ChrisHammond/DNNTemplates).

A third but more ugly solution would be to create a standalone aspx page and iframe it.