# Session-duration-only access control to DNN pages

Tags: asp.net, security, authentication, dotnetnuke

We have a customer with an unusual request for the security of a subset of a DotNetNuke / Evoq website.

This is a special set of pages that should only be accessed by a large group of a company's employees to make preferred-discount purchases.

Rather than trying to maintain a set of thousands of user accounts, having the employees register to gain access passwords, they just want to have the employee get to a welcome page, provide their email address (which will be confirmed as from that company's domain) and then be sent a link or a link and temporary rotating passcode that grants access to that set of pages for just the duration of their session once they visit the link.

I've searched for any type of 3rd party module to accomplish this with no luck.

It has also been suggested this might be accomplished through some type of URL-masking process, which I suppose might even be done by a proxy outside of DNN.

Has anyone provided a similar type of security solution before, either within DotNetNuke or through a proxy?

Comment: Adding role to users and the limit the page to that role doesn't help?

Comment: Thanks, Mehdi. I think we are needing to create a layer that sits on top of the User / Role built into DNN. The idea is to somehow grant temporary auto login based on a user having a valid email address pattern rather than having to maintain a bunch of individual DNN logins. Thanks!

Comment: I think you will need to create your own custom login module.

Comment: See my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45326464/dnn-module-import-file) on how you can get started on that.