# Complex text file to XML-File transformation

Tags: c#, xml, schema

I want to create a XML-File with following .txt.

The following objects have all the same structure. Is it possible to create a XML?

I don´t need the whole content of the .txt. Only "Information ObjectX, Delta X, Delta Y, Delta Z, all Rotations, CALLOUT and PART_TYPE" are important and neccessary.

At its best, I want to convert these Files directly in a C# program.

Thanks for your help!

```
 ============================================================
Created by             : Muster
Date                           :  13.11.2017 10:10:10
Activated component            : File
Node name                      :  abc123abc
============================================================
Information Object # 1

Name                 Object1
File-Path        FilePath
Component-Path       Component-Path
Typ                  Component

Color                2 (Green)
Component-Typ        Body
Version          301   01 Jan 2017 10:10 (Created by Muster)

Object is visible

Positions:

Delta X              =   5.00000000010
Delta Y              =   16.0000000001
Delta Z              =   20.0000000200

Rotations:

X-vector             XC =    0.0                  X =    0.0              
                     YC =    1.0                  Y =    1.0              
                     ZC =    0.0                  Z =    0.0              

Y-vector             XC =   -1.0                  X =   -1.0              
                     YC =    0.0                  Y =    0.0              
                     ZC =    0.0                  Z =    0.0              

Z-vektor             XC =    0.0                  X =    0.0              
                     YC =    0.0                  Y =    0.0              
                     ZC =    1.0                  Z =    1.0              

Component is xxx
3 Rotations- and Translations available

------------------------------------------------------------


------------------------------------------------------------

CALLOUT    = 4890 (string)
PART_NAME = body head (string)
PART_TYPE = Item (string)

************************************************************

Information Object # 2

Name                 Object2
File-Path        FilePath
Component-Path       Component-Path
Typ                  Component

Color                2 (Green)
Component-Typ        Body
Version          301   01 Jan 2017 10:10 (Created by Muster)

Object is visible

Positions:

Delta X              =   5.00000000010
Delta Y              =   25.0000000000
Delta Z              =   20.000000200

Rotations:

X-vector             XC =    0.0                  X =    0.0              
                     YC =    1.0                  Y =    1.0              
                     ZC =    0.0                  Z =    0.0              

Y-vector             XC =   -1.0                  X =   -1.0              
                     YC =    0.0                  Y =    0.0              
                     ZC =    0.0                  Z =    0.0              

Z-vektor             XC =    0.0                  X =    0.0              
                     YC =    0.0                  Y =    0.0              
                     ZC =    1.0                  Z =    1.0              

Component is xxx
3 Rotations- and Translations available

------------------------------------------------------------
------------------------------------------------------------

CALLOUT    = 4891 (string)
PART_NAME = body head (string)
PART_TYPE = Item (string)
```

Comment: Is it possible to create a XML? Yes. You can parse the file for the content that you want and then write it to xml. Have you tried anything yet?

Comment: I still tried to convert it into a XML-File. It isnt possible for me, to parse only the content I want and also I can´t create the correct structure for my XML.
Do you have an example for me, how I can select the content I want and insert it into XML?

Comment: [Here is a question that shows how to parse a text file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/858756/how-to-parse-a-text-file-with-c-sharp).
You can read the lines that you want and create a object that represents the xml data structure, that can then be written to xml.

Comment: Thanks, it will help me a little bit. I think my example is a bit different to this.
Would it be a problem, if you give me an example, maybe for the line "Delta X" or "PART_TYPE"? This would be very helpful for me

Comment: Are you looking for a way to understand the actual content of each line? Try looking at the topic of Regular Expressions.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

As requested here is part of the reader that reads the Delta X, Y & Z.
You can read the line and check if it `StartsWith` Delta. You can `Split` the line on the equals sign and `Trim` the string and then parse to a decimal value. You can then repeat this for the other Delta values.

```
//values to store the delta values in
decimal deltaX, deltaY, deltaZ;
//The reader for the text file
using (var reader = new StreamReader("filename.txt"))
{
    string line;
    //read file line by line
    while ((line = reader.ReadLine()) != null)
    {

        //Check if line starts with Delta 
        if (line.StartsWith("Delta"))
        {
            //For this line you can split by  '=' and then read the second value in the array, trim the string and parse to a decimal value
            deltaX = decimal.Parse(line.Split(new[] {'='})[1].Trim());
            //move reader to next line as we know it will be DeltaY & repeat
            reader.ReadLine();
            deltaY = decimal.Parse(line.Split(new[] { '=' })[1].Trim());
            reader.ReadLine();
            deltaZ = decimal.Parse(line.Split(new[] { '=' })[1].Trim());
        }
    }
}
```

Feel free to have a go at the Part_X and other lines you want to read. If you have any problems add the code to the question and people will help where they can.